# Mysql down after restarting server

Tags: mysql, webserver, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1.

For some reason the server was working too much on a process with high load, so I powered off and restarted the machine. After that, Mysql stopped working and couldn't be restarted anymore.

I checked the error log at /var/log/mysql/error.log but it's empty.

When I tried to restart the service and I got the following messages:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status mysql.service:

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since jue 2019-08-22 18:58:05 -04; 41s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 12020 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 12056 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

journalctl -xe:

```
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x955d0c]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x93b08e]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x93cd7f]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa1dd9d]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa670b6]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9ba375]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f8ba90256ba]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: x86_64/clone.S:111(clone)[0x7f8ba84cc41d]
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
ago 22 18:58:32 servidor1 mysqld[12230]: information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.


ago 22 18:58:52 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12400): Error: sql(dmiranda@comercialkod.cl,152.172.252.195): Password query failed: Not connected to database
ago 22 18:58:52 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth: Error: auth worker: Aborted PASSV request for dmiranda@comercialkod.cl: Lookup timed out
ago 22 18:58:52 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:58:53 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:58:54 servidor1 dovecot[904]: imap-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts in 62 secs): user=<dmiranda@comercialkod.cl>, method=PLAIN, rip=152.172.252.19
ago 22 18:58:58 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:59:01 servidor1 CRON[12687]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ago 22 18:59:01 servidor1 CRON[12686]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ago 22 18:59:01 servidor1 CRON[12688]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/cron.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log
ago 22 18:59:01 servidor1 CRON[12689]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.l
ago 22 18:59:01 servidor1 CRON[12686]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
ago 22 18:59:23 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:59:25 servidor1 su[12004]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
ago 22 18:59:25 servidor1 sudo[12003]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
ago 22 18:59:27 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:59:28 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:59:33 servidor1 dovecot[904]: auth-worker(12673): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server throug
ago 22 18:59:34 servidor1 sudo[12790]: surempresa : TTY=pts/20 ; PWD=/home/surempresa ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
ago 22 18:59:34 servidor1 sudo[12790]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ago 22 18:59:34 servidor1 su[12809]: Successful su for root by root
ago 22 18:59:34 servidor1 su[12809]: + /dev/pts/20 root:root
ago 22 18:59:34 servidor1 su[12809]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
ago 22 18:59:34 servidor1 su[12809]: pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
```

However, I managed to restart the service after I tried the solution from this post:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008298/cant-start-mysql-server-database-corruption

So I set:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 9
```

But, it doesn't work well since some database tables are now read only.

What should I do instead? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really an expert, but what about your error log? Should be at /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: @Samuel actually I have been checking the error log but it's empty